# Goncharov's signature

Tags: одним-словом

I am trying to make sense of Goncharov's signature as it appears [in this book](https://archive.org/stream/polnoesobranies04goncgoog?ui=embed). Although I am familiar with the cyrillic alphabet in print, I am unable to see Goncharov's name there. Is it really there or is it something else?

Comment: Yes, that's his signature. It has И.-the first letter of his name and the rest is his surname.

Answer (score 3):

> Although I am familiar with the cyrillic alphabet in print

Russian handwritten script is quite different from a printed one, just like it's in English.

> Is it really there?

Yes, his signature is rather clear. It's "**I**" followed by a dot (i.e. Ivan) and "**Gonchar**" with some curly tail (probably "ov" yet merely unreadable as it's normal with signatures) which also provide a closure of the first letter "G".